# Octave Installation Directory

Tags: matlab, octave

After installing Octave GUI, I am getting the following error message:

`Please define the octave.exe installation directory.`
`i.e. C:\Octave\Octave3.6.0_gcc4.6.2\bin`

I tried to look up some posts here on SO with no luck. Google wasn't much of a help either. Any help would be much appreciated as to how I can fix this.

Comment: Seems you only downloaded a GUI for Octave which is not bundled with octave itself. If so download Octave it will contain the octave.exe

Comment: I have. I in fact downloaded Octave first.

Comment: There is no need anymore to install the GUI and the interpreter separately. [GNU Octave 3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/) comes with an **official** GUI. Please use it instead.